-라고 role in -더라고 grammar pattern
So, I understand that this pattern is used to report a personal observation or experience from the past, and -더- acts as a retrospective suffix conveying past personal experience or observation, but is -라고 the same as the quotative marker used for quoted or reported speech?
I am asking since I've also seen the pattern used as -더라 and this should be more a sentence-ending rather than a quotative particle, but it definitely seems to be related in some way due to the meaning of the grammar expression.

Yes, your analysis is correct. This is a grammaticalisation of retrospective -더- (which in itself derives from -던) + declarative-quotative -라고. As 손호민 (2013) states in a paper on Korean emergent modal endings (EMEs):

It is assumed that, due to the repeated main clause omission in 고 constructions in conversation, the omission became gradually conventionalized, making the main clause unrecoverable and orphaning the quotative particle 고 in the utterance-final position. Thus, the orphaned 고 gradually coalesced with the preceding sentence-type ending, as per Lehmann’s (1985) principle of “coalescence”, to become an EME through structural reanalysis (e.g., changing a word boundary to a morpheme boundary, decategorizing a quotative particle to a modal suffix) and semantic-pragmatic shift (e.g., subjectification and intersubjectification).

The quotative is generally conceptualised as quoting from the first person only, i.e. "I report that". Note how the quotative -(ㄴ/는)다고 also developed into a first-person "I assure you that".

Notice that the innovated EME retains the reportive meaning inherited from the omitted predicate, as per Hopper’s (1991) principle of persistence.

